# How do i implement the JPanel and JLabels of one class in another to the frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, awt

Im currentl programming a pacman  style game and i`m doing the gui right now. My Plan is to write seperate Gui classes and in this example i wrote the Gui for my Hearts. My plan is to combine all the Gui classes in one MainGui which will incude the JFrame and which is operated trough a seperate main class. But i dont know how i show the JPanel and JLabel from my Heart Class in the Maingui class.

```
package Gui;

import java.util.Formatter;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class GuiHearts extends JFrame {
    JFrame frame;
    JLabel heart1;
    JLabel heart2;
    JLabel heart3;
    JPanel tPanel;
    ImageIcon Hearts;
    Image image;

    int heartUpdate = 0;

    public GuiHearts(){
        Hearts = new ImageIcon("Herz1.png");
        image = Hearts.getImage().getScaledInstance(20, 30, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
       // image = image.getScaledInstance(1000,1000, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        Hearts = new ImageIcon(image); // Das Bild "Herz1.png" wird 

        Border BFrame = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green, 3);

        heart1 = new JLabel();
        heart1.setIcon(Hearts);
        heart1.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        //heart1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        heart1.setSize(20, 30);

        heart2 = new JLabel();
        heart2.setIcon(Hearts);
        heart2.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        heart2.setSize(20, 30);

        heart3 = new JLabel();
        heart3.setIcon(Hearts);
        heart3.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        heart3.setSize( 30, 30);

        //Die if-Schleife wird benötigt um über das heartUpdate der Logik dem 
        //Gui zu sagen wie viele Herzen angezeigt werden sollen
        if (heartUpdate == 1){
            heart1.setVisible(false);
            heart2.setVisible(true);
            heart3.setVisible(true);
        } else if (heartUpdate == 2){
            heart1.setVisible(false);
            heart2.setVisible(false);
            heart3.setVisible(true);
        } else if (heartUpdate == 3){
            heart1.setVisible(false);
            heart2.setVisible(false);
            heart3.setVisible(false);
        }
        

        tPanel = new JPanel();
        tPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        tPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 50));
        tPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,15,15));
        tPanel.add(heart1);
        tPanel.add(heart2);
        tPanel.add(heart3);

        frame = new JFrame(); //creates a frame 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //exit out of application
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        frame.setSize(750,750); //sets size
        frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
        frame.add(tPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

This is the Maingui class

```
package Gui;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import Gui.GuiHearts;

public class GuiMaster extends JFrame {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel tPanel;


    public GuiMaster(){

    
        tPanel = new JPanel();
        tPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        tPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 50));
        tPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 15, 15));


        frame = new JFrame(); //creates a frame 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //exit out of application
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        frame.setSize(750,750); //sets size
        frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
        frame.add(tPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tPanel.add(new GuiHearts().heart1);
    

    


    }
public static void main (String args[]){
    new GuiMaster();
}
}
```

Comment: You have two classes that extend `JFrame`.  Your application should have one `JFrame`.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: 1) Why are you adding an empty panel to the frame? The content pane of the frame is a JPanel with a BorderLayout. You can just add the GuiHearts pane directly to the frame. Read the Swing tutorial on [Using Top Level Containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) to better understand the structure of Swing. 2) Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.